# IndexedDB - iPad Safari (ver: 10 & above) jquery.bind not working

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad, bind, indexeddb

**Description:**

I've a function that gets the records from the indexedDB. When it is called by binding the function call to an element using 'jquery.click' it is working fine, but **when I bind the same element using 'jquery.bind' it crashes the webapp.** When debugging I found that app crashes on request.onsuccess event.

**Platform:** Ipad (iOs version 10 & above) , Safari browser

**Problem:**  'jquery.bind' is not working.

**Scenarios I tried:**

1. I tried by binding the element without calling the indexedDB related function - **worked fine**
2. I tried in Windows Tab - **worked fine**
3. using jquery.click - **worked fine**
4. While binding the element using jquery.bind - **crashes the webapp**

**Example:**

```
$('#ABC').bind('click', function(e) {
 var transaction = db.transaction(['Table1'],'readonly')
 var objStore = transaction.objectStore('Table1');
 var request = objStore.getAll()
 request.onsuccess = function (event) {
       console.log(event);
 })
```

})

In the above scenario, the app crashes when the event is fired but if we use jquery.click, then it works fine.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a global database variable and attempting to reuse the same database connection for the lifetime of the app. There is no guarantee that at the time of a click event, the database is defined and open. It may not have opened yet, it may have closed, it may not even be defined as a variable. First try that.

Other notes:

- For a transaction on a single table you do not need []
- Log error messages for your requests or your transaction, so you have more useful information
- Up to you, but readonly is implicit because it is the default, no need to specify it
- You really need to be more specific about what a crash means. The way your question is currently worded makes it difficult to help.

Answer (score 0):

`getAll()` on IDBObjectStore is not supported until Safari 10.1 (see http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb2) - I don't think that's been released with an iOS update yet. (At least, my iPhone reports 10.0 in the user agent.) Are you sure this is working on the platform in other cases, or is the error just going unreported?

As the other Josh noted, it's hard to tell exactly what problem you're seeing - if by "crash" you're getting an exception, can you tell us what the exception message is?

Comment: getAll actually does hard crash Safari if used in a Web Worker https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=172434 - the bug is fixed but seems the fix is not yet included in the current version.